# Bash - draw a vertical line behind lines with variable length

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, text-formatting

I have a textfile that has the following format and I want to add a vertical line after those lines, followed by increasing numbers:

```
c4-1 d e c
c d e c
e-2 f g2
e4 f g2
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c
c-1 r c2
c4 r c2
```

I achieve the line and the numbering with the following `while-loop`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ]; then
        echo
        continue
    fi
    n=$((++n)) \
    && grep -vE "^$|^%" <<< "$line" \
    | sed 's/$/\ \|\ \%'$(("$n"))'/'
done < file
```

and get an output like:

```
c4-1 d e c | %1
c d e c | %2
e-2 f g2 | %3
e4 f g2 | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c | %6
c-1 r c2 | %7
c4 r c2 | %8
```

now I want the addition to be vertically aligned and get an output like this:

```
c4-1 d e c            | %1
c d e c               | %2
e-2 f g2              | %3
e4 f g2               | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c    | %6
c-1 r c2              | %7
c4 r c2               | %8
```

this would mean I need to somehow get the line length of the longest line (here: 21 characters) and the line length of each line and add the difference with spaces, how could I achieve this?

Comment: use can use `wc -L` to get length of longest line in a file.. and then use printf formatting

Comment: @Sundeep cheers mate, figured it out using `wc -L`. Though this attempt is pretty slow. Freddies answer using `column` is pretty awesome, check it out :-))

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice would help you understand why it is slow

Comment: @Sundeep, [SE Comment Link Helper](//stackapps.com/q/2378) can help you make more readily readable links to other Q&As in SE. Like for your link: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could print the lines without alignment and format the output with `column -t` and a dummy delimiter character:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    echo
    continue
  fi
  printf '%s@| %%%s\n' "$line" "$((++n))"
done < file | column -e -s'@' -t | sed 's/ |/|/'
```

Here, I added a `@` as dummy character before the `|` indicating the end of the column.
The `sed` command at the end is used to remove one additional space character before the `|`. Option `-e` is needed to keep empty lines in the output.

Output:

```
c4-1 d e c            | %1
c d e c               | %2
e-2 f g2              | %3
e4 f g2               | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c    | %6
c-1 r c2              | %7
c4 r c2               | %8
```

Comment: nice one! Did not think of using `column`. Was about making it complicated by subtracting line length from the longest lines characters and repeating the spaces. Cheers! <3

Comment: Is the `if` statement defensive programming?

Answer (score 9):

Using `awk` + GNU `wc` assuming all characters in the input are single-width:

```
$ awk -v f="$(wc -L < ip.txt)" '{printf "%-*s | %%%s\n", f, $0, NR}' ip.txt
c4-1 d e c            | %1
c d e c               | %2
e-2 f g2              | %3
e4 f g2               | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c    | %6
c-1 r c2              | %7
c4 r c2               | %8
```

Comment: You've got to read the file twice.  Fine for most files; less good if huge.

Answer (score 5):

Plain bash: works with bash version >= 4.0

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t lines < file
max=0
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    max=$(( ${#line} > max ? ${#line} : max ))
done
for i in "${!lines[@]}"; do
    printf "%-*s | %%%d\n" $max "${lines[i]}" $((i+1))
done
```

For older bash versions, replace mapfile with a while-read loop: this works with version 3.2

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
lines=()
max=0
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "line" ]]; do
    lines+=("$line")
    max=$(( ${#line} > max ? ${#line} : max ))
done < file
for i in "${!lines[@]}"; do
    printf "%-*s | %%%d\n" $max "${lines[i]}" $((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no `@` characters in the data (just replace the two `@` used here with another character in that case):

```
$ awk -v OFS='@| %' '{ print $0, FNR }' file | column -s '@' -t
c4-1 d e c             | %1
c d e c                | %2
e-2 f g2               | %3
e4 f g2                | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c  | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c     | %6
c-1 r c2               | %7
c4 r c2                | %8
```

This uses the string `@| %` as the output field separator and prints the input followed by the line number of each line (separated by this separator), then uses `column` to align this on the `@` characters (these will be removed).

---

If you're fond of `sed` or of awkward regular expressions, you could always number the lines with `cat -n` or `nl -b a` and then move the line numbers to the end of the line and insert `@| %` using `sed`, before calling `column`:

```
$ cat -n file | sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]*(.*)$/\2@| \%\1/' | column -s '@' -t
c4-1 d e c             | %1
c d e c                | %2
e-2 f g2               | %3
e4 f g2                | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c  | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c     | %6
c-1 r c2               | %7
c4 r c2                | %8
```

---

Using `awk` to read you file twice, once to figure out the maximum line length (`m`) and again to format the lines to this length. `column` is not use here (or in the last solution):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { m=(length>m?length:m); next } { printf("%-*s | %%%d\n", m, $0, FNR) }' file file
c4-1 d e c            | %1
c d e c               | %2
e-2 f g2              | %3
e4 f g2               | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c    | %6
c-1 r c2              | %7
c4 r c2               | %8
```

Notice that the filename is given twice on the command line.

---

Same as above, but storing the file in memory as an array (`a`), and printing it according to the longest line length at the end.  Disk access is benefitted to the decrement of memory consumption:

```
$ awk '{ a[FNR]=$0; m=(length>m?length:m) } END { for (i=1; i<=FNR; ++i) printf("%-*s | %%%d\n", m, a[i], i) }' file
c4-1 d e c            | %1
c d e c               | %2
e-2 f g2              | %3
e4 f g2               | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c    | %6
c-1 r c2              | %7
c4 r c2               | %8
```

Comment: THX, the `awk` ones are all damn fast - NICE!  **EDIT:** well the `sed` one too!

Answer (score 2):

just for the records: (this is horribly slow, but was my first attempt using `wc -L`)
definitely going for the answer of @Freddy using `column`!

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

ll=$(wc -L < "$file")

while read -r line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ]; then
        echo
        continue
    fi
    sl=$(wc -L <<< "$line")
    if [ "$ll" = "$sl" ]; then
        as=$(echo "$ll - $sl" | bc)
    else
        as=$(echo "$ll - $sl + 1" | bc)
    fi
    space=$(printf '\ %.0s' $(seq "$as") )
    n=$((++n)) \
    && grep -vE "^$|^%" <<< "$line" \
    | sed "s/$/$space\ \|\ \%$(printf "%s" "$n")/"
done < "$file"
```

though it is working with one additional space:

```
c4-1 d e c             | %1
c d e c                | %2
e-2 f g2               | %3
e4 f g2                | %4
g8-4\( a-5 g f\) e4 c  | %5
g'8\( a g f\) e4 c     | %6
c-1 r c2               | %7
c4 r c2                | %8
```